# C'est quoi la signification du mot « chaud » dans ce cas exceptionnel?

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai lu un commentaire sur le sujet de Stéphane Poussier, qui a été placé en garde à vue pour « l'apologie du terrorisme ». Voilà le commentaire:

> Après c'est **chaud**, si être un c-----d envoie en garde à vue, il va falloir tripler les effectifs de la police.

Je n'ai jamais vu cette utilisation de « chaud ». C'est quoi la signification exacte du mot « chaud » ici ?

Comment: Juste pour compléter la réponse : ce n'est pas un usage exceptionnel. C'est même assez courant. C'est du langage assez familier, en revanche.

Comment: Détail qui n'a rien à voir avec la question. C'est vraiment écrit « c-----d » dans le commentaire ? Ça m'étonne un peu car il me semble que ce genre de fausse auto-censure n'est vraiment pas habituel en français.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Vous avez raison, je l'ai censuré moi-même. Je n'étais pas sûr que le mot serait accepté ici, mais clairement j'avais tort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans ce contexte, c'est synonyme de *dangereux*, *sujet à tensions*, voir [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaud) :

> d) *P. méton.*
>   − D'un point de vue favorable. [En parlant d'une chose qui reflète, exprime une personnalité] Plein de chaleur humaine. *Atmosphère chaude. Le café Lipp, tout chaud d'âme et d'intimité* (Fargue, *Le Piéton de Paris*, 1939, p. 56).
>   − D'un point de vue défavorable. [En parlant d'une chose qui a trait à l'activité hum. (événement, période, lieu)] Où il y a de l'animation, des disputes, des oppositions d'idées, d'intérêts. *La campagne du referendum fut des plus chaudes* (G. Vedel, *Manuel élémentaire de dr. constitutionnel*, 1949, p. 305).
>   ♦ Spécialement
>   Où il y a des échanges de coups, du sang qui coule. *Après deux heures d'un combat très chaud, Dégo fut repris* (Las Cases, *Le Mémorial de Sainte-Hélène*, t. 1, 1823, p. 351).
>   Où il y a des tensions sociales, politiques, de l'agitation, un climat de crise. *Point chaud*. *« Chaud, chaud, le printemps sera chaud », répétaient-ils [des lycéens manifestant]* (*La Croix*, 14 mars 1975, p. 8, col. 4).
>   *Arg.* Dangereux. *Les communistes je ne m'en occupe pas; c'est trop chaud. Le Soudi ne peut pas les encaisser* (H. Bazin, *Le Bureau des mariages*, 1951, p. 106).